# Check if comma separated string contains in another comma separated string

Tags: php, string

I m having trouble checking if a comma separated string contains another comma separated string.

Suppose I have two strings

```
$stringA="red,blue,yellow,green,black,grey,purple,pink,khaki,lemon,orange,white,maroon";
$stringB="blue,green,white,pink,maroon";
```

All I want to check is whether colors in `$stringB` is contained in `$stringA` or not?? The only way I could think of is converting `$stringA` into an array, and checking the colors one by one using `in_array` function. Is there another easier way around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's what I would do. Split into an array and compare the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stringA="red,blue,yellow,green,black,grey,purple,pink,khaki,lemon,orange,white,maroon";
$stringB="blue,green,white,pink,maroon";

$arrayA = explode(',', $stringA);
$arrayB = explode(',', $stringB);

$min = min(array(
    count($arrayA),
    count($arrayB),
));

$AcontainsB = ($min == count(array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB)));
```

Comment: that solution is pretty slow

Comment: Agreed, it is not webscale.

Answer (score 2):

I think comparing arrays is not bad idea, but you can also do something like that:

```
$stringATmp = ','.$stringA.',';
$colors = explode(',', $stringB);
$contains = true;
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    if (strpos($stringATmp, ','.$color.',') === false) {
        $contains = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of doing it that are faster than others, but no ways that are conceptually easier than loading the data into some kind of data structure.  Since you are talking about checking a list of items in arbitrary order against another list of items that can be in arbitrary order, there are no shortcuts around getting the reference list (stringA) into a data structure, and then looking up the stringB list in that data structure.

One way to speed it up.

1. Explode stringA into an array.
2. array flip the stringA array so that the colors become keys in the array (it does not matter what the values are).
3. Now you can look up each color from an exploded String B by with code like the following:

Something like this:

---

```
$stringAArray = explode(',', $stringA);
$stringAArray = array_flip($stringAArray);
$stringBArray = explode(',',$stringB);
$itemsToFind = count($stringBArray);
foreach ($stringBArray as $colorFromB) {
    if (array_key_exists($colorFromB, $stringAArray)) {
        $itemsToFind--;
    }
}
if ($itemsToFind == 0) {
    echo "All B items are in A"
}
```

---

This is a very fast lookup and scales well for lots of items in A and B.

Final note:  for smallish arrays, doing it via `in_array` is going to be comparably fast.

Comment: BTW, I think @dev-null-dweller's solution is particularly elegant.  Mine probably scales better, but as a paradigm of how to do this for arrays of the size you are using, you can't beat dev-null-dweller's approach for simplicity and elegance.

Comment: @lupatus:  Thanks for the correcting edit on the foreach.  You were right.  Your edit was rejected before I got a chance to approve, I don't know why.  Thanks!